# What happens when you break the "No talk rule"?

Tags: live, rules, wsop, casino

I just read the [Is trash talking legal in WSOP?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/954/is-trash-talking-legal-in-wsop) question and answer and it made me wonder, what kind of punishment would you get for breaking the no talk rule?

Also, I wonder, do casinos have similar rules? And what happens if you play in a casino and break their no talk rule?

Comment: This youtube video shows how one player was given a penalty that consisted of sitting out of the game (wile still paying the blinds): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QN6IR6BKIqQ

Comment: alas, that link has broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the thread You linked, there are a lot information about this topic.
I try to make a little summary here.

Official poker rules doesn't say too much about behaviour at the tables(nearly nothing). There are a document, made by the Poker Tournament Directors Association, that defines a collection of rules to make the game better, simpler and more ethic. Many big tournaments use these rules (mostly in America). You can find the rules [HERE](http://www.pokertda.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Poker_TDA_Rules_2011_Version_2.0_PDF_longform.pdf).

As you can see, on the last page there are a few sections about the penalty problem, saying:

> Tournament staff can assess a 1-hand penalty,
>   1-, 2-, 3-, or 4-round penalties or 
>   disqualification.

So, even with these rules, the penalty depends on the tournament staff and the exact situation. Since it is impossible to define a rule for every type of sentence a player can say, there used to be an experienced judge, who decides about the penalties. This judge can be a [floorman](http://www.poker-babes.com/poker/definitions/floorman/), or, in smaller casinos the dealer him/herself.

It is possible, that some casinos and tournaments make their own rules and penalties to make the situations and the decisions more simple. If You want to play at a casino and it has its own rules, You should read them to avoid bad surprises like disqualification. If the casino has no such a collection of rules, You can not refer to some general poker rules(to defend your behaviour), You will be in the hands of the judge.